# Wordpress - Posts 2 Posts: Invalid argument error

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I am using posts 2 post to connect my custom post types. Everything seems pretty good so far except, listing my connections in archive. I have two connection assigned to one custom post type. that's why I am using `each_connected` method https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/each_connected described here.

```
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'movie'
));
p2p_type( 'movies_to_actors' )->each_connected( $my_query, array(), 'actors' );
p2p_type( 'movies_to_locations' )->each_connected( $my_query, array(), 'locations' );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php

echo '<p>Actors:</p>';
foreach ( $post->actors as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();

echo '<p>Filming locations:</p>';
foreach ( $post->locations as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();

endforeach;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

When I try to get data from 2 connections it gives
`warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` in error.

But if I use any of them alone there is no error. I would be glad if you help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually overwriting your variable `$post`

change `$post` to something else let say `$p`

```
echo '<p>Actors:</p>';
foreach ( $post->actors as $p ) : setup_postdata( $p );
    the_title();
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();

echo '<p>Filming locations:</p>';
foreach ( $post->locations as $p ) : setup_postdata( $p );
    the_title();
```

**Update:**

for the issue `warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

I think the `$post->locations` is not set properly or is not an array just add an condition

```
if ( isset($post->locations) && is_array($post->locations) ) {
    echo '<p>Filming locations:</p>';
    foreach ( $post->locations as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        the_title();
}
```

Comment: hey Zzlalani, thanks for pointing out clearly. When I changed variable to $p I still get the same error.

Comment: foreach ( $post->locations as $p ) : setup_postdata( $p );

second for each line

Comment: I tried it and it didn't show up any results and also didn't give error. I put else statement, and printed else results.

interesting thing is: when use them alone they both give results but when I try both connection I have this weird issue.
thanks for the help

Comment: I ended up using Further nesting method posted in github wiki of the plugin. It works fine. Thanks for the help Zzlalani.